# iterate through JSOn result

Tags: c#, ajax, json

I have a WebMethod being called from ajax, trying to iterate through the returned data. The data being returned is "{ BusinessTypeID = 2 }".  I'm trying to figure out how to just get the value 2?

```
        //Function called from ajax
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] GetTerminalBusinessTypes(string terminalID)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    try
    {

        var terminalBusinessTypes = (from bt in db.BusinessTypes
                                    join obt in db.OxygenateBlenderBusinessTypes on bt.BusinessTypeID equals obt.BusinessTypeID
                                    where obt.OxygenateBlenderID == Convert.ToInt32(terminalID)
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        bt.BusinessTypeID
                                    }).ToList();


        for (int i = 0; i < terminalBusinessTypes.Count(); i++)
        {
            results.Add(terminalBusinessTypes[i].ToString());
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

The ajax function:

```
            function PopulateTerminalBusinessTypes(terminalID) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "OxygenateBlenderCertificationApplication.aspx/GetTerminalBusinessTypes",
            data: "{'terminalID':" + terminalID + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var targetValue = data.d;

                var items = $('#cblTerminalBusinessType input:checkbox');



                                    $.each(targetValue, function (key, targetValue) {
                                        alert(data[index].BusinessTypeID);
                                    });
                    }
        })//end ajax

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the data being returned is not "{ BusinessTypeID : 2 }"? If so, you can refer to it as targetValue.BusinessTypeID or targetValue['BusinessTypeID']

Comment: I tried that already, didn't work.  Maybe it's the way I'm returning the data?  I'm trying to figure that out now....

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I cannot see where your "index" is defined.

Shouldn't the alert line read

```
$each(targetVale, function(key, item) {
   // on second look, this wont work as you are converting toString()
   alert(targetValue[key].BusinessTypeId)
   // this should
   alert(item)
});
```

You could also throw a debugger; line above the alert and see the values being traversed.

Answer (score 0):

When your web service returns the json value, asp.net wraps in an object, with the key being `d` and the value being your json string. Review [this link](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/) for more info.

You have to parse the value string into a json object. Using jQuery (v1.4.1 or higher):

```
jQuery.parseJSON(targetValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try returning a JSON string from C#:

```
public static **string** GetTerminalBusinessTypes(string terminalID)
...
var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(results);
return sJSON;
```